# Animation in edit mode

Tags: animation, edit-mode

Is it possible to animate faces and edges in edit mode ?

For example, set a keyframe for face location and animate it till translated under z-axis 10 units, etc.

Similar question with edges.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot animate directly in Edit Mode but you can make hooks that allow animation via Object Mode. You can do the same for edges. The hotkey is <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Off-topic, but how did you bring up that mode wheel? The one that gave you options like Object mode, Vertex Paint, etc.

Comment: It's the Pie-menu addon which comes with Blender - just have to tick it. Find it very helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to @Patdog's solution: you can use shape keys to set individual mesh/vertex locations and then keyframe the influence value.

[image]

To set a keyframe, go to your starting frame, move your mouse over the value parameter and press "I" to set a keyframe. Go to your next frame, move the value and press "I" again while over the value to set the next keyframe.

Comment: Is it possible to animate using armature in edit mode? So, bone would handle one face rotations or translations?

Comment: I dont really understand the question. Could you explain a bit more what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you want to rotate/translate the particular faces of the mesh but not all. So, some faces rotate around it's origin and come to their own original location on the mesh.